# Sourcetree, Mercurial and several branches

Tags: mercurial, branch, branching-and-merging, atlassian-sourcetree

We have here in mercurial repository, for example, two development branches (I am writing the code in one branch), where code changes intensively in parallel before merging with default branch.

Please help me to take changes from other development branch into mine? Can I do this trought SourceTree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do merge with SourceTree.

Let's say that your branch name is `dev1` and the other branch name is `dev2`.

To merge changes in `dev2` branch to `dev1` branch do following (commands are available under Repository menu, or right click popup menu)

- Select `dev1` branch -> **Update To**
- Select `dev2` branch -> **Merge** -> dialog will ask you Are you sure you want to merge 'dev2' into your current branch -> **OK**
- Resolve conflict if there are any and **Commit**

Note: As general rule when you are doing something in your repository and you are not quite sure how it will end up, I suggest that you create backup copy of your repository first. In case that anything goes wrong, just restore the backup.